# Best way to execute HTTP GET in onCreate()

Tags: java, android, rest, android-asynctask, retrofit

I'm coding an Android client that connects to a REST API. Since Android 3.0 it is not allowed to perform blocking network operations on the main thread, so I'm looking for the best way to implement this.
I have managed my objective using `AsyncTask` but it seems a rather dirty implementation so I'd like to ask for advice.
The data returned from the async task is used to update the UI.

`MainActivity.java`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    ListView establishment_list;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        establishment_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.establishment_list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter( this, R.layout.establishment_row_layout, new String[]{"Loading data..."} );
        establishment_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.establishment_headerview, null);
        establishment_list.addHeaderView(header);
        // GET establishments from REST API
        new NonBloquingGET().execute();
    }

    /* DIRTY IMPLEMENTATION */
    private class NonBloquingGET extends AsyncTask<List<Establishment>, Void, List<Establishment>> {

        List<Establishment> establishments;

        @Override
        protected List<Establishment> doInBackground(List<Establishment>... params) {
            /* This is a synchronous call using the Retrofit library*/
            establishments = Client.getInstance().getEstablishments();

            return establishments;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Establishment> result) {
            Log.d("ASYNC TASK", result.toString());
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Establishment e : result){
                data.add(e.getName());
            }
            adapter.updateDataSet( data.toArray(new String[data.size()]) );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do it as I'm planning to add more Activities and adding an AsyncTask class for each seems awkward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you can start with is to make your inner `AsyncTask` class implementation `static`, otherwise it will hold an implicit reference to the host class (`Activity`), this means it won't be garbage collected until task is alive (let's imagine execution of `NonBloquingGET` takes a lot of time (you are sitting with dial-up speed somewhere on a desert island) and you rotate the screen, activities will be kept in memory). The second step you can think of is to implement a pair of [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). After you understand the key concepts behind it, you can take a look on 3rd party libraries, for example [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for network communications, [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) for events and [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) for event bus.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are suggesting to create an Intent whenever I want to load data and send it to an IntentService. That IntentService does the data adquisition on background and sends a broadcast to whatever BroadcastReceiver I have set up. But wouldn't I need a Broadcast Receiver for each class I'd like to make data adquisition in?

Comment: @fernando4870 in general, yes. If you are making async operation, you should notify main thread somehow, that data is arrived. You can bind broadcast receiver to the activity lifecycle with LocalBroadcastManager. Actually the question you asked is very broad, and possible solutions are published in multiple articles. You can also read this article http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/, which shows one of the possible solutions how to create background worker.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncTask` is actually a good thing as the execution of that is not synchronized with the main activity and so when you want to do some background work and need the main UI to be active at the same time always use `AsyncTask`.

The drawback of doing network operations on the main thread is that it'll make the UI unresponsive for the time being which will look too laggy and is not a good habit.

Answer (score -2):

static {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

With this code you  can use network operations on your main thread.